# Introducing Edited Files Into a Git Branch and then merging

Tags: git, svn

This situation I have is the following.
I have an old project in a a Solution I will call `Old Project A` and `Old Solution A`. It was a divergent branch (just a copy of the SVN for development) from the main Project and Solution. This was in SVN Tortoise. I have a copy of this `Old Project A` and `Old Solution A` on my computer.

Then we put the main line of our solution and project into Git. Much development has taken place and there are many commits in Git.

So I now have The `Git Project A` within `Git Solution A`.

I want to introduce The `Old Project A` into a branch of the Git repository.

What I have done is created 2 new branches I will call `NewBranch A` and `NewBranch B`, both from the master branch.

From `NewBranch B` I deleted the `Git Project A` and replaced it with `Old Project A` , committed all the modified files but did not commit all the deleted files (which had been added in the newer `Git Project A`).

```
git checkout NewBranch B
git merge NewBranch A
```

But this just keeps the `Old Project A` code and does not merge the `Git Project B`. I was of course expecting merge conflicts. I wanted them to sort them out manually. But all I got was the `Old Project A` code.

How can I merge the `Old Project A` code with the `Git Project B` and then manually sort the conflicts ?

Comment: I can see 2 options for your situation. #1, just use Meld or other merging tool to merge manually on the new branches. This is more controlled. But if you insist on using git, #2 create the NewBranch from very first git commit of master branch instead from latest master. Copy all old code there and commit. Now merge latest master to NewBranch. This should trigger conflicts as you expected and you can resolve conflicts manually.

Comment: @MohanaRao Meld seems to be the best option that I am using now. I have a very old repository with lots of conflicts but I think Meld is good

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 options for your situation.

1. Just use Meld or other merging tool to merge manually on the new branches. This is more controlled.

But if you insist on using git,

2. Create the NewBranch from very first git commit of master branch instead from latest master. Copy all old code there and commit. Now merge latest master to NewBranch. This should trigger conflicts as you expected and you can resolve conflicts manually.